# Where to implement fifo and lifo in xv6

Tags: c, scheduling, fifo, xv6, lifo

I am currently doing a homework with xv6, i need to implement FIFO and LIFO with the following style of code:

```
#define IFO 1
#if IFO==1
  DO FIFO HERE
#endif


#if IFO==2
  DO LIFO HERE
#endif
```

What xv6 file should i modify to implement those scheduling policies. Any tip of what should i do, i am newbie using xv6 and i don't understand much of what i am doing. Also, the homework include an extra file called sched_test:

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"
#include <time.h> 

void delay(int number_of_milliseconds){ 
    // Converting time into milli_seconds 
    int milli_seconds = number_of_milliseconds; 

    int start_time = uptime(); 

    while (uptime() < start_time + milli_seconds) ;
} 
int main(){ 
    // Creating first child 
    int n1 = fork(); 
    int count = 0;
    int times = 20; 
    int millisec_to_wait = 5;

    // Creating second child. First child 
    // also executes this line and creates 
    // grandchild. 
    int n2 = fork(); 

    if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0) 
    { 
        printf(1,"\n0.- parent ID: %d\n",getpid());
        while(count < times){
            printf(1,"0 ");
            delay(millisec_to_wait); 
            count++;
        }
    } 
    else if (n1 == 0 && n2 > 0) 
    { 
        printf(1,"\n1.- first child ID: %d\n",getpid()); 
        while(count < times){
            printf(1,"1 ");
            delay(millisec_to_wait); 
            count++;
        }
    } 
    else if (n1 > 0 && n2 == 0) 
    { 
        printf(1,"\n2.- second child ID: %d\n",getpid()); 
        while(count < times){
            printf(1,"2 ");
            delay(millisec_to_wait); 
            count++;
        }
    } 
    else { 
        printf(1,"\n3.- third child ID: %d\n",getpid()); 
        while(count < times){
            printf(1,"3 ");
            delay(millisec_to_wait); 
            count++;
        }
    } 

    while(wait() >= 0);
    exit(); 
}
```

I already included it on MAKEFILE, and execute, make clean, make and make qemu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your implementation in `proc.c` in the `scheduler()` function. Here's where it is [in vanilla xv6](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/proc.c#L323). In basic xv6, it just loops over the process table to find the first process. You'll want to add you own data structure that you'll use in `scheduler()` to determine which processes to run next. This is an important part of that function with some notes:

```c
    // LOOP OVER SOME DATA STRUCTURE TO FIND A RUNNABLE PROCESS
    acquire(&ptable.lock);
    for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
      if(p->state != RUNNABLE)
        continue;

      c->proc = p;
      switchuvm(p);
      p->state = RUNNING;

      swtch(&(c->scheduler), p->context);
      switchkvm();

      c->proc = 0;

      // ADUJST YOUR DATA STRUCTURE TO AFTER RUNNING THE PROCESS
      #if OWNSCHED==1
          // Add to the end of some D/S
      #elif OWNSCHED==2
          // Add to the beginning of some D/S
      #endif
    }
    release(&ptable.lock);
```

You could add a data structure to the `ptable` struct in `proc.c` to track the order of processes to run then loop over this in `scheduler()`. Of course, that means you'll have to modify some other functions such as `allocproc()` to add new processes in the appropriate places. Some of the rest depends on a few things, like if you're allowed to use a static array to store processes or if you must use a linked list instead.

If you haven't already, I highly recommend reading Chapter 6 of [the xv6 book](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/xv6/book-riscv-rev0.pdf). It was really helpful when I had to implement an MLFQ in xv6!